# recommended way to use command line options for icinga/nagios checks?

Tags: nagios, icinga

Short version:  if I want to change one of the "command definitions" in the Nagios set, what is the best way to do it?

For example, I would like to add the `-f` (follow) flag to one of the check_http commands found in `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg`.  But it feels wrong to be editing those files.

Should I edit the existing commands to meet my needs?
Should I add my own command to the `http.cfg` file to meet my needs?
Is there a place where I can add my own command file?

Pointers to the docs are gladly welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own command with a new name in `etc/objects/commands.cfg`, something like this:

```
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
        }

define command{
        command_name    check_http_redirect
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ -f $ARG1$
        }
```

and call it with corresponding state which you want to handle in `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg`:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               domain.com
    service_description     domain.com
    check_command           check_http_redirect!warning
    process_perf_data       0
    contact_groups          admin
    }
```

An example when running from the command line:

```
$ check_http -H domain.com -f warning
HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently - 428 bytes in 0.003 second response time |time=0.002897s;;;0.000000 size=428B;;;0
```